# How to get the value of a dropDown control?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ribbon

dropDown on the ribbon:

```
<dropDown id="dd01"
onAction="dd01OnAction"/>
```

In VBA I need

```
Sub dd01OnAction(control As IRibbonControl, ID As String, index As Integer)
If dd01.Value = "Sky" Then MsgBox "323"
End Sub
```

How can I get the value of dropDown ?

Comment: What are the values and how do you load them into the dropdown?

Comment: @OlleSjögren, Excuse me for late. dd01 is populated by cells values of a range. I suppose I need to refer to these cells, but they are dinamically changed.

Comment: I usually load the dropDowns from a collection and make sure that the ID in the collection matches the index in the dropdown. That way I can get all relevant values from the collection based on the `index` parameter in the callback. Could you use something similar?

Comment: @OlleSjögren, does that mean that after each change in Collection, I need to Invalidate ribbon ? Mamma Mia, it will be almost after each click.

Comment: I'm afraid it does. However, by using `ribbonobject.InvalidateControl("ID")` you can invalidate just the specific dropDown control, not the whole ribbon.

Comment: @OlleSjögren, thanks, I see now the solution. You should maybe place your comments as answer, so I could vote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the value directly.

I usually load the dropDowns from a collection object and make sure that the ID in the collection matches the index in the dropDown. That way I can get all relevant values from the collection based on the index or ID parameter in the callback. Could you use something similar as a workaraound?

> does that mean that after each change in Collection, I need to Invalidate ribbon ? Mamma Mia, it will be almost after each click

Yes, however, by using `ribbonobject.InvalidateControl("ID")` you can invalidate just the specific dropDown control, not the whole ribbon.

Very brief example:

```
Sub dd01OnAction(control As IRibbonControl, ID As String, index As Integer)
    '***** Assumes that MyCollection is initialized elsewhere
    '***** and filled with strings :)
    Debug.Print "The value is " & MyCollection.Item(index)

    If MyCollection.Item(index) = "Sky" Then MsgBox "323"

End Sub
```